# Connect Excel workbook to an arbitrary (not SQL) database

Tags: sql, excel, google-cloud-datastore

This [guide](http://helpdeskgeek.com/office-tips/excel-to-mysql/) explains how to connect an Excel workbook to an SQL database. Is there a way to do the same for an arbitrary database? Specifically to Google Datastore?

Also, does this sort of connection follows an obscure protocol, or is it something that's relatively easily implemented?

Answer (score 1):

Apprantely, i dont think so there is any way by which you can connect your Excel Workbook to Google Datastore directly.However you can use the JavaAPI datastore object to connect your application to Google datastore.Refer to the document [1] for how to use remote API in java to access the Google datastore.

[1] **https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi**